# Is there a way to refresh the contents of HomeStacks screen in react expo on every click?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, refresh, use-effect

I'm developing a mobile app with react expo. I have a menu that fetches a list of items.  Unfortunately, it only fetches data on the first click. When I navigate from one menu to another it does not refresh the data.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsListGET();
  },[]);

  const getItemsListGET = async () => {
    try {
      await refreshTokens(tokens.refreshToken).then((response) => {
        dispatch(
          pushAlltoken({
            token: response.data.token,
            refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken,
          })
        );

        try {
          setloading(true);
          axios
            .get(`${myURL}`, {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data.token}`,
              },
            })
            .then((result) => {
              setMyliste([...new Set([...myliste ,...result.data.list])])
              setloading(false);


            }).then(
              
            );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("there was a problem in getitems function", error);
          setloading(false);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error from all function ", error);
      setloading(false);
    }
  };
```

And the code of the navigation is the following

```
    export default function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <HomeStacks.Navigator headerMode={"none"}>
      <HomeStacks.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerTitle: "Home" }}
      />

      <HomeStacks.Screen
        name="Product"
        component={Product}
        options={{ headerTitle: "Product" }}
      />

    </HomeStacks.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can u add your code for the click, when you navigate from one menu to another

Comment: I hope the code I added to the post is what you were asking for

Answer (score 0):

You should add the screen name variable (or something like that) in `useEffect`'s dependencies array.

When the value of the variable changes, the effect will be rerunned and the data will be loaded again.

Cannot be more specific, because there is not enough code.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.                                                                                   
 useEffect(() => {
    getItemsListGET();
  },[props.state]);